# Directory.CreateDirectory from [TestMethod] behaves strangely

Tags: c#, testing, filesystems, directory

I'm really in the dark on this one... I've created some batch processing code, and have several tests that setup a directory structure before calling the method to be tested. The problem can be illustrated by

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void StupidTest()
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory("./XXX");
        Assert.IsTrue(Directory.Exists("./XXX"));
        //new FileInfo( "./XXX/YYY.txt").Create().Close();
    }
```

When the last line is commented out, the tests runs perfectly, but in the "Out" folder of the testresults, no folder is created. When the last line is included, the test runs as well, and both the XXX folder and YYY.txt file exist in the "Out" folder for the test run. If only the last line of the test is included in the body, the test fails, complaining about a non-existant path.

I found some references mentioning something about file system virtualization, and the test app not having enough permissions to create folders in the "Out" folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is odd.  Try stepping into the method and checking that the current directory (Environment.CurrentDirectory) is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Environment.CurrentDirectory is indeed set to the "Out" folder of the current test run.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint after the directory is created, can you see the directory in Explorer?  Can you create a directory in explorer yourself while paused at the breakpoint?  (I'm assuming your test is running locally in your user context.)

Comment: good point, but strange result... If I put a breakpoint on the Assert, the folder does exist in the "Out" folder, it's only after the test is completed, that it disappears again...

As a rule, I observe that everything works as expected (assertions and such), just after the test completed, all empty folders seem to disappear... The question is why ?

Answer (score 0):

can you try and use ProcessMonitor (from MS download site,free), and record all of the activities of that process, and then we can see if the directory gets created, moved , deleted and so on.